# Encodable JSON dictionary in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift4, decodable

With the help of @matt. I was able to solve it and the finished code is below for anyone who will encounter similer issues in the near future. 
Given the below JSON

```
{
    "restaurants": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "restaurantName": "Chuks",
            "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
            "status": "Working",
            "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
            "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "restaurantName": "Chuks",
            "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
            "status": "Working",
            "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
            "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "restaurantName": "Chuks",
            "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
            "status": "Working",
            "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
            "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "restaurantName": "Chuks",
            "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
            "status": "Working",
            "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
            "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "restaurantName": "Chuks",
            "restaurantPicture": "restaurantImages/benards.jpg",
            "status": "Working",
            "workingDays": "Tuesday to Sunday",
            "workingHours": "3pm to 10pm"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I am trying to access the arrays within the Dictionary with this code into a table. So I have made a Struct. Below is the content of my Structfile.

```
    struct Response: Codable {

    let restaurants: [Restaurant]

    struct Restaurant: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let restaurantName: String
        let restaurantPicture: String
        let status: String
        let workingDays: String
        let workingHours: String
    }
}
```

This is my main View Controller

```
        import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


        @IBOutlet weak var tabelView: UITableView!

        var restaurants = [Response]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            downloadJSON {
                self.tabelView.reloadData()
            }

            tabelView.delegate = self
            tabelView.dataSource = self

        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return restaurants.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

            cell.textLabel?.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].restaurantName.capitalized

            return cell
        }


        func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping ()->()){

            let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8888/tableview/tableView.php")

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

                if error == nil{
                    do{
                        let downloadedRestaurants = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
        print(downloadedRestaurants.restaurants.map{$0.restaurantName})

        self.restaurant.append(downloadedRestaurants)


                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completed()
                        }
                    }catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()

        }
    }
```

Thanks @matt. I hope this piece becomes useful to other newbies or anyone who is having similar issues
Cheers!

Comment: Your code is silly. Instead of `print("JSON Error")` put `print(error)` so you can find out what the error _is_.

Comment: @matt I have update the struct fill to decode the dictionary now please how do I access the restaurantName in the dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to decode as `[RestaurantStats]`. But look at your JSON! It is not an array of RestaurantStats. It is not an array at all. It is a dictionary with a single key, `"restaurants"`. You need to create *that* struct and decode as *that*.

**EDIT** Since I gave my answer, you have revised your code to declare an outer struct Response. And that's correct — and is exactly what I said you should do. So decode as Response and you're all set.

Comment: I have updated the question now I am getting                    
Value of type 'Response' has no member 'restaurantName'  how can I access the restaurantName

Comment: I told you in my answer.

Comment: Your JSON is not an array of dictionaries. It is a dictionary. So my answer remains the same. You need to decode as the struct (now called Response).

Comment: I copied and pasted _your_ JSON string and _your_ new Response struct into an app and I had no difficulty using Response to decode the JSON. So I would say that my answer is proven correct: if you do what I said to do, it works fine. You are 9/10 of the way there.

Comment: now I have update the code and I am able to print(restauran.restaurants) but I want to get only the restaurantName when I try print(restauran.restaurants.restaurantName) it gets error says Value of type '[Response.Restaurant]' has no member 'restaurantName'. I am kinda stuck here

Comment: The error message is very clear. `restauran.restaurants` is an array of Restaurants. You have to say which one you want. For example, do you want the name of the first one? Then that is `restauran.restaurants[0].restaurantName`.

Comment: Or do you want an array or all the names? Then use `.map`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and everything, I am new to swift and trying hard to get my feet dirty... I know you can access array base on its index but I am trying to access all the names in the array. I am looking into how to use .map